# Swift: Error - Initializer for conditional binding must have Optional type, not 'Void' (aka '()')

Tags: ios, swift, nsuserdefaults, option-type, nskeyedarchiver

Using Swift 3, blog reader app reading from a MYSQL database using JSON and PHP. User has the ability to save the blog they want to keep getting updates from using a follow button (as well as unfollow button). Instead of saving the entire array, just trying to save the followed blogs ID so the app just finds the blogs id and shows that specific blog that the user followed.

This is the error I'm getting when loading the user defaults

> Initializer for conditional binding must have Optional type, not 'Void' (aka '()')

This error is in `func loadUserDefaults()` in `MainController.swift` at first line `if let data = UserDefaults.`.
After the user clicks the follow button, I move the cells between arrays, between sections in the tableview and then I call `saveUserDefaults()`

This is `MainController.swift`

```
var mainArray = [Blog]()
var followedArray = [Blog]()
var filteredArray = [Blog]()
var followedIdentifiers = Set<String>()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // Receiving Data from Server
    retrieveDataFromServer()

    // NSCoding - Unarchiving Data (followedID)
    loadUserDefaults()
}

// NSCoding: Archiving UserDefaults
func saveUserDefaults() {

    // Saving to UserDefaults
    let encodedData = NSKeyedArchiver.archivedData(withRootObject: self.followedIdentifiers)
    UserDefaults.standard.setValue(encodedData, forKey: "followedID")
    UserDefaults.standard.synchronize()
}

// NSCoding: Unarchiving UserDefaults *** ERROR IS HERE ***
func loadUserDefaults() {

    // Unarchiving Data -- ERROR: THIS FIRST LINE --
    if let data = UserDefaults.standard.setValue(Array(self.followedIdentifiers), forKey: "followedID"),

        let myFollowedList = NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveObject(with: data) as? [Blog] {

        self.followedIdentifiers = myFollowedList
        self.followedIdentifiers = Set(UserDefaults.standard.stringArray(forKey: "followedID")!)

    } else {
        print("Error/ Empty: (Loading UserDefaults (followedID))")
    }
}

// Retrieving Data from Server
func retrieveDataFromServer() {

    let getDataURL = "http://example.com/receiving.php"
    let url: NSURL = NSURL(string: getDataURL)!

    do {
        let data: Data = try Data(contentsOf: url as URL)
        let jsonArray = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: .mutableContainers) as! NSMutableArray

        // Clear the arrays
        self.followedArray = [Blog]()
        self.mainArray = [Blog]()

        // Looping through jsonArray
        for jsonObject in jsonArray {

            if let blog = Blog(jsonObject:jsonObject as! [String : Any]) {

                // Check if identifiers match
                if followedIdentifiers.contains(blog.blogID) {
                    self.followedArray.append(blog)
                } else {
                    self.mainArray.append(blog)
                }
            }
        }
    } catch {
        print("Error: (Retrieving Data)")
    }
    myTableView.reloadData()
}
```

This is `Blog.swift` which handles all the blogs objects and NSCoding

```
class Blog: NSObject, NSCoding {

var blogName: String
var blogStatus1: String
var blogStatus2: String
var blogURL: String
var blogID: String
var blogType: String
var blogDate: String
var blogPop: String


private init (name: String,status1: String,status2: String,url: String,id: String,type: String,date: String,pop: String) {
    blogName = name
    blogStatus1 = status1
    blogStatus2 = status2
    blogURL = url
    blogID = id
    blogType = type
    blogDate = date
    blogPop = pop
    super.init()
}

convenience init?(jsonObject: [String:Any]) {

    guard let bID = jsonObject["id"] as? String,
        let bName = jsonObject["blogName"] as? String,
        let bStatus1 = jsonObject["blogStatus1"] as? String,
        let bStatus2 = jsonObject["blogStatus2"] as? String,
        let bURL = jsonObject["blogURL"] as? String,
        let bType = jsonObject["blogType"] as? String,
        let bDate = jsonObject["blogDate"] as? String,
        let bPop = jsonObject["blogPop"] as? String

        else {
            print("Error: (Creating Blog Object)")
            return nil
    }

    self.init(name: bName, status1: bStatus1, status2: bStatus2, url: bURL, id: bID, type: bType, date: bDate, pop: bPop)

}

convenience required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    guard let blogName = aDecoder.decodeObject(forKey: "blogName") as? String,
        let blogStatus1 = aDecoder.decodeObject(forKey: "blogStatus1") as? String,
        let blogStatus2 = aDecoder.decodeObject(forKey: "blogStatus2") as? String,
        let blogURL = aDecoder.decodeObject(forKey: "blogURL") as? String,
        let blogID = aDecoder.decodeObject(forKey: "blogID") as? String,
        let blogType = aDecoder.decodeObject(forKey: "blogType") as? String,
        let blogDate = aDecoder.decodeObject(forKey: "blogDate") as? String,
        let blogPop = aDecoder.decodeObject(forKey: "blogPop") as? String else {
            print("Error: (Creating Blog Object)")
            return nil
    }
    self.init(name: blogName, status1: blogStatus1, status2: blogStatus2, url: blogURL, id: blogID, type: blogType, date: blogDate, pop: blogPop)
}

func encode(with aCoder: NSCoder) {
    aCoder.encode(blogName, forKey: "blogName")
    aCoder.encode(blogStatus1, forKey: "blogStatus1")
    aCoder.encode(blogStatus2, forKey: "blogStatus2")
    aCoder.encode(blogURL, forKey: "blogURL")
    aCoder.encode(blogID, forKey: "blogID")
    aCoder.encode(blogType, forKey: "blogType")
    aCoder.encode(blogDate, forKey: "blogDate")
    aCoder.encode(blogPop, forKey: "blogPop")
 }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The line of code:

```
let data = UserDefaults.standard.setValue(Array(self.followedIdentifiers), forKey: "followedID")
```

makes no sense since setValue method doesn't return any values. 
Looks like you need to replace it with (Swift 3):

```
let data = UserDefaults.standard.data(forKey: "followedID")
```

**Updated** with @closetCoder comment

Comment: Or better perhaps to use:

`let data = UserDefaults.standard.data(forKey: "followedID")`

Answer (score 1):

The setValue function is a void function so it can't be assigned to the variable data since it has no return value.

Here is the documentation for UserDefaults from Apple: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/userdefaults